# Is it possible to add files to Android app folders in /data/data?

Tags: android, file, root, whatsapp

I'm beginner programmer in general. 
Is it possible to add files to Android app folders in /data/data using my app on a non-rooted device? I'm planning to make an app using C++ and I’m not using Android Studio IDE, my app should add whatsapp stickers to whatsapp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for security reasons. You can put files in *your app's* portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), but you cannot put files into *other apps'* portions of internal storage.